# Automate file uploading with AppleScript and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, automation, applescript

I'm trying to automate part of my workflow that involves uploading a series of images through a web page with an AppleScript that calls JavaScript in the already-loaded page.

I've done this sort of automation before, but am hitting a major roadblock when it comes to actually picking the files for upload. I can't set the `input.value` property (it's not allowed, for security reasons), and I can't even figure out how to get the page to put up the file picker, which I could then hopefully populate. The page uses Angular, in case that helps to come up with a solution.

This is what the page's HTML looks like (the relevant section):

```
<div class="...">
    <div class="..." ng-class="...">
        <span class="... ng-binding" ng-bind-html="...">Choose File</span>
        <div class="...">
            <input id="..." type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I simulate clicking "Choose File" using JavaScript loaded into the page's DOM?

Answer (score 0):

This does essentially what you're saying. The most hopeless part for me was the javascript parts, but luckily i found some premade applescript javascript functions on a site called cubemg.

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName

to getValueFromClass(theclass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        tell document 1
            set theFirstTableHTML to do JavaScript "\n document.getElementsByClassName('" & theclass & "')[" & num & "].value"
            return theFirstTableHTML
        end tell
    end tell
end getValueFromClass


on run
    choose file with prompt "Which folder would like average file size calculated?"
    open {result}
end run

on open theimage
    --tell application "Finder" to set xx to every file in item 1 of theimage
    --display dialog "Hey! the file's alias is: " & (path of theimage as string)
    --display dialog theimage
    set filepath to POSIX path of theimage

    tell application "Safari" to open location "https://upload.vstanced.com"
    delay 2
    clickClassName("btn btn-big white outline", 0)
    tell application "System Events"
        activate application "Safari"
        delay 0.5
        keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down} --open goto
        set the clipboard to filepath
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        delay 0.7
        keystroke return -- enter goto text
        delay 0.4
        keystroke return --press enter on file

    end tell
    delay 1
    clickClassName("btn btn-big green", 0)

    set thedirectlink to ""
    repeat 15 times
        set thedirectlink to getValueFromClass("r2", 1)
        delay 1
        if thedirectlink is not equal to "" then
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    set the clipboard to thedirectlink
    tell application "Safari" to close current tab of window 1

    display notification "Upload complete" with title "VStanced Upload" subtitle thedirectlink sound name "blow"
end open
```

If you want to check this out, save it with the file format "application" in script editor. Then make sure safari is open (or lengthen the delays) and use it by dragging an image on to the script (you could put it in your dock or on your desktop). After you do that, it does the following

1. opens new tab
2. goes to image hosting site
3. opens the "file choosing sub-window"
4. opens the goto thingy
5. pastes the path in
6. hits enter twice (first for goto, then for the choose file window itself)
7. waits for the direct link to load, copies it to clipboard, closes the tab, and "runs" a notification with sound

Even with the premade functions, i had a hard time finding classes/ids that worked.

That's probably largely because i spent a long time trying to see if i could somehow just paste or drag+drop the file into the browser using some combination of applescript and javascript. i still think theres gotta be a way to avoid doing so many keystroke things and using so many delays. even if there was just a way to "drag and drop" that would help so much.

Also, the page doesn't refresh when you click the button to open the choose file window, so i feel like there is some field in the html that can be set to the files path using javascript. i just don't know what its called.

if you find or found another way to open the "file choosing window" please let me know.